# when tk().event_generate('<Button-1>', x, y) on a top level frame/window does the click get applied to the lower level widgets e.g. Button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have access to the top level tkinter window, but when I do:

```
self._root = tk.Tk()
<snip>
x = 10 # in screen coordinates
y = 20 # in screen coordinates
self._root.event_generate('<Button-1>', x=x, y=y)
self._root.event_generate('<ButtonRelease-1>', x=x, y=y)
```

I expect the button click to be applied to the widget underneath location x,y on the window. In this example a Button.

My understanding is event_generate places an event on the message queue inside tkinter just like a real mouse click would do. Normally clicking anywhere inside a window or a frame, causes the click to go through the top-level panes until it finds a widget with a bind() associated with it, i.e. a Button.

And so using that I should be able to simulate a button click anywhere on the window without moving the actual mouse.

But it doesn't do anything, no click, no error, no anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why bother when you could just use `button.invoke()` ?

Comment: This is for a generic facility for testing Tkinter apps. I won't necessarily be able to get access to the button object to call invoke() on it.

Comment: You will need to use ctypes or a third party library. Python tkinter does not support it. I have tried nearly every possible combination of [eventfields](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.html) with different values pairs. Not sure if a tcl script will solve it, but it seems possible in [tcl tk](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/event+generate)

Comment: @Thingamabobs: I think you're trying too hard. Tkinter can tell you what widget is under a specific coordinate. I've successfully written record/playback tools in tk before (except for menus, which are tough to drive programmatically since they are typically managed by the OS).

Comment: @BryanOakley I just tried to trigger `ButtonPress` years ago and it didn't worked out, so I had coded around with `invoke`. I just wanted to find out if I'm now able to make it work. But it ensures me, that this is the right approach, when a experienced tkinter programmer like you says it is the right way to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event_generate` is not the same as simulating a click by the user. Instead, you're explicitly specifying the window that is to receive the event.

If you need to simulate the actions of a user, you can use the method `winfo_containing` which will return the widget at a given coordinate. You can then pass that widget to `event_generate`.

Comment: The underlying GUI library TK/TCL and pretty much every gui library on the planet handles mouse clicks by generating an event and putting it on the message queue. There is some code that checks what window below that coordinate has a handler. It has to be that way since you can have a pane on top of a button that prevents the mouse click from reaching the button. So calling it on a specific widget object is bypassing how the UI actually works.

Comment: @JohnA: _"So calling it on a specific widget object is bypassing how the UI actually works"_ - yes, it is. This is very useful, just not in the way you want it to be. It's not designed to be a general purpose emulate-the-user feature, it's specifically designed to send an event to a specific widget.

Comment: @JohnA: if you really want to emulate user button presses, you can do that yourself pretty trivially. You can use `winfo_containing` to figure out what widget is under the cursor and then target your event to that widget. It's one extra line of code.

Comment: ok that sorta worked. The winfo_containing() got the right widget w. And if I use w.invoke() it clicks the button. But if I use w.event_generate() the click doesn't work.

And I found another post you did where you talked about using update(). That had no effect for me.

I'm going to be using this for Entry widgets, Radio Buttons. etc.  Should I be worried?

Comment: When you click on a widget, there’s more than just clicking going on. The cursor enters the widget which generates a `<Enter>` event. Some of the built in bindings don’t do anything if the cursor isn’t actually over the widget. It takes a lot more work to simulate user behavior than just simulating clicks.

Comment: Sweet, thank you! 

 I got it to work with event_generate: Enter, Button-1 and ButtonRelease-1 

And I got it to work with update() as well (hey just in case)

I'll post the code later tonight so it's nice and clear for other folks.

Answer (score 0):

With @Bryan Oakley's excellent help, I was able to get this to work:

```
# the top level window
self._root = tk.Tk()  
<snip>
x = 10 # in screen coordinates
y = 20 # in screen coordinates

# get a reference to the widget in the root window that is
# underneath coordinate x,y
w = self._root.winfo_containing(x, y)

# Note: the <Enter> is necessary. Without it the 
# button events don't do anything.
w.event_generate('<Enter>', x=x, y=y)
w.event_generate('<Button-1>', x=x, y=y)
w.event_generate('<ButtonRelease-1>', x=x, y=y)

# The invoke() also works.
# w.invoke()
```

Note: the widget in this sample is a Button. Here's a snippet of code for an Entry widget:

```
    x = 30
    y = 40
    w = self._root.winfo_containing(x, y)
    print(f'DBG {w.winfo_class()}') # should be 'Entry'

    msg = 'abcd'
    w.focus_set()
    for ch in msg:
        w.event_generate(f'<KeyPress-{ch}>')
    w.update()
```

There is much more to be done here e.g. checking how special characters are done e.g. backspace, tab, enter key, ctrl and alt keys etc. But it's a start.